# Best way to reference a subset of instances in a map?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, composition

I am working on multibody simulations. In my code's hierarchy, a (physical) `System` has several `RigidBody`s stored in a table `std::map<std::string, RigidBody>`. Each `RigidBody` instance similarly has a series of `Node`s stored in a table. These `Node`s can be flagged as *special*.

I would like the `System` to have a way to access the *special* nodes.

I could do this by, e.g., creating a `std::vector` of `std::reference_wrapper`s to those `Node`s. However, if the `Node` or its parent is destroyed, the reference is left dangling.

I could also define a function that iterates through every `RigidBody` and `Node`, but it seems rather inefficient, since the number of `Node`s can be large.

What approach would not involve dangling pointers/references, but would also not require to iterate through every `Node` only to access the flagged instances?

Comment: In this case it might be very helpful if you specify what language version you can use. The dangling reference issue is probably not going to go away because I think most efficient solutions would be "view" like. So I think any solution direction should involve the map being a member of a class that can maintain the invariant. And the view you should then access through a getter (and recalculate it if the collection changed since last call). And use the returned view only locally for a short time.

Comment: Maybe another solution is to maintain two lists of Nodes in a RigidBody one for normal nodes and one for special nodes. But still make the map a member of a RigidBodies class you are going to have to maintain some invariants in all cases.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think maintaining two Node lists at RigidBody, then using a function at System to iterate through all RigidBody's "special" list is a good compromise. The RigidBody list at System should of course be maintained as well.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whenever I am worried about dangling pointers or references, I take it as a sign that I have to rethink my ownership-model. It sounds to me like a RigidBody owns its nodes, but the system may borrow them for a certain amount of time. The thing in the STL that resembles this model the most is probably a (private?) `std::shared_ptr<Node>` owned by the RigidBody and a `std::weak_ptr<Node>` borrowed by the system. Using these types comes with some penalties, like reference counting and using heap storage. But then elements of a map are stored on heap anyway.

Comment: **system** consists of **named bodies** (a mapping). **Body** can be  **simplex** (with geometric and mechanical features), or **complex** (with **named bodies** and an **accessor function** that returns a **view of externally accessible bodies**. Anytime system interacts with a body, it can call the accessor, get a view and manipulate bodies; but it should not cach the view for future use. This a simple OO design problem. Implementation can use smart pointers or `std::vaiant` (if the number of types remains small with low variations in size).